# Does anybody have practice in programming PCMEF - architectures?

Tags: architecture, prolog

PCMEF is an architecture style presented in the book **Practical Software Engineering** by Maciaszek and Liong. The layers are:

**P**: Presentation
 **C**: Controller
 **M**: Mediator
 **E**: Entity
 **F**: Foundation.

It is some kind of enhancement compared with MVC - architecture. I recommend it to interaction, data and communicating - oriented purposes. I have programmed it using Visual Prolog. Foundation in my applications is the data model (domains) for the application.

PCMEF is like a simulated computer: Presentation is the display, Controller the user interface and event handling, Mediator the internal logic and data highway. Entity is the database or external interfaces and F defines the knowledge.

This is a really nice small architecture. Does any other have experiance of it?

Comment: Discussion = community wiki, please.

Answer (score 1):

Django?

http://blog.worldmaker.net/2006/feb/09/the-django-framework-architecture/